# Time of MySQL database removal

Tags: mysql

Is there a method where we could probably find when a MySQL database was removed/dropped from the server? Is this logged anywhere? Does it have a separate logfile which probably needs to be enabled in the configuration file?

Additionally, this is a cPanel server, but there's nothing logged in the cPanel access-logs (or error-logs for that matter). [DROP TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-database.html), too doesn't specify anything in this regard (from 5.0 to 5.6).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: The database that was deleted was an InnoDB database. (thankfully, we have backups)

As @longneck suggested, I checked [BINLOG EVENTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-binlog-events.html), using the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956106/how-to-know-if-mysql-binary-log-is-enable-through-sql-command) but this seems disabled at the moment.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_bin       | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: How was the database stored? Innodb? Memory? MyISAM?

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

If binary logging is enabled, you can use [`SHOW BINLOG EVENTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-binlog-events.html) statement or the [`mysqlbinlog` utility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to search the binary logs for DROP statements.